# Can I update Salesforce event trigger record in my Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

In my Journey I have setup Salesforce data as my entry source (on created), I see there is an option to update Salesforce data but only the Contact. Is it possible to update the entry object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update any Sales/Service cloud object you can identify using the "Object Activity". Identification can either be done by matching any field value or in the best case using an id.

As in your case the entry event contains the object you like to update, you can select "Simple Update" when configuring the activity.

**Documentation articles:**

- [Sales and Service Cloud Canvas Activities](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/sales_and_service_cloud_canvas_activities/)
- [Object Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/sales_and_service_cloud_canvas_activities/the_object_activity/)
- [Update an Object Record](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/sales_and_service_cloud_canvas_activities/the_object_activity/update_an_object/)